# How to access the variables of C++ program from gdb with Python

Tags: python, c++, debugging, gdb, automated-tests

How can one access the values like these using the Python from gdb?:

```
some_array_smartptr->operator[](0)->item // no errors are checked for sake of clarity
```

In gdb this line works fine, but I cannot figure out how to use it in Python as I am implementing the automated testing.

Please note, that both vector and smartptr are not standard, but are manually written. Semantics is the same though.

Comment: Can you provide some more context around how you're accessing your program? I'm looking at this via the Review Queue and not a C++ developer, so I'm not able to answer, but it looks like there's room for improved clarity here.

Comment: Currently my tests look like Python code which contains a list of strings line `"variable_x == value"` which elements execute one by one adding `if gdb.parse_and_eval(item)` and `then` clauses. I basically don't need any python code, it is kind of a wrapper for gdb lines and I'd like to simplify it. In fact, I use gdb lines just because the Python syntax to access the values is not clear and I'd like to clarify it (as I stated in the first sentence of the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gdb.parse_and_eval()` should do exactly what you want for live-process debugging.

[Documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Basic-Python.html).

> I'd like to iterate through some arrays an so on.

The `parse_and_eval` returns a `gdb.Value`. Once you have that value, you can use any of the `Value`s methods for further access.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17172404/50617).

Comment: Yes, this is what I currently do. The thing is, I'd like to iterate through some arrays an so on. In case of parse_and_eval() this looks really as wrong approach. Am I missing something?